# filesize() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path - PHP

Tags: php, web, file-read

I am tryig to read an entire file in PHP, but I have this issue with filesize function. Here is the code:

```
<?php
 $file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
 echo $file;

 $fsize = filesize($file);
 //$ftext = fread($file, $fsize);
 //echo $ftext;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter should be the string of the path of the file, not the file itself.
Try this: `$fsize = filesize("file.txt");`

Answer (score 2):

The answer is right there in the question title: you need to pass `filesize` a path, not the `$file` object you get from `fopen`:

```
$fsize = filesize("file.txt");
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as the solution.